# How to enable the UPI payment method in CCAvenue merchant account

Tags: ccavenue

I am integrating the CCAVenue payment gateway in my website but i couldn't find any option of UPI payment method in billing page when the customer pay for the product ! i did search for that but unable to find it google and other site if anyone knows then tell us !!!

just tell us how to make it enable